# Mongoose connection that is rarely used (keep alive?)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my applicaiton I have a DB to which the code will periodically connect, but it will be quite rarely use (maybe once a day/week).

Can I create just connect while module (app) init and then use it across the module while application run lifecycle?

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.SOME_DB)
```

I'm not sure should I have a keep alive option as suggested in mongoose docs:

```
options.server.socketOptions = options.replset.socketOptions = { keepAlive: 1 };
mongoose.connect(uri, options);
```

or standard auto reconnect feature will be enough?

An i'm also not what is "long running applications"? Actually any real-time service is long running application, should keep alive be enabled for all such services in production?

Also not sure what are Connection pools and how they can affect.

Comment: Note that keepAlive is a number, not a boolean value, that represents the number of ms the connection needs to timeout until a new connection is made. For this reason, setting it to 1 is a very bad idea because mongoose will make new connections when it actually shouldn't.

Comment: I had this enabled in production and my application was making thousands of connections and it constantly took my DB down, causing it to step down and switch to my replica (and back, etc.). Highly recommended to set keepAlive to a larger value. I set it to 2000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reference to this in the Mongoose documentation:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

And yes, it's generally a good idea.

Also in that document Connection pools are explained. But generally speaking, Mongoose is keeping several socket connections open to the server/replica-set/mongos instances rather than one to allow concurrent processing of requests. Yes, even with async call-backs on IO there is wait time, so Connection pools allow another channel to talk on while one is busy.

And yes, it's generally a good idea.

Comment: An i'm also not what is "long running applications"? Actually any real-time service is long running application, should keep alive be enabled for all such services in production?

Comment: That's pretty much it. Anything `short-lived` would just be a quick script or process invoked periodically. And while developing/testing you typically restart a lot. Keep-Alive is a **good** option for services that need to keep in communication with other services.

Comment: And what about actually common REST services server backed with (remote) mongodb? Should I use keep alive for my general mongoose connection?